# Django: Migrations not recognizing cloudinary?

Tags: python, django, database, migration, cloudinary

Hey I am trying to replace storing files to using cloudinary in my django app. I add

```
image2 = CloudinaryField('image')
```

to my models.py and run make migrations but nothing happens. Then when I run the server I get the error that image2 column does not exist. anyonee know what is gong on?

Answer (score 0):

The following steps should work for you:

1. Adding `image2 = CloudinaryField('image')` to your `models.py` file
2. ./manage.py makemigrations myapp
3. ./manage.py migrate myapp

Make sure you run the `migrate` instruction as well

`

Comment: I get the error "django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "my app_mymodel" already exists"

Comment: This doesn't seem like a Cloudinary related issue. Furthermore, the suggestions given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36806461/cloudinary-not-being-recognized-in-django) sounds reasonable, did it work for you?